# OpenVPN redirect-gateway not working on 3G cellular

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I have trouble setting up an OpenVPN server on Ubuntu 14.04.
I followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) from Digital Ocean step by step and it works perfectly for all WiFi devices such as my laptops and desktop either on Linux (Ubuntu fork), OS X 10.11 or Windows 7 or 10. It also works on my iPhone (iOS 9 latest beta) when connecting on WiFi.

However, when I want to use my 3G connection with Free Mobile (French carrier), it doesn't work.

I tried to comment out the `push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"` on the server. I can now browse websites, but my public IP is no more the one of the VPN.

The only clue I could have found seems to be [here (FR)](http://linuxfr.org/forums/linux-android/posts/configuration-openvpn-en-udp-sur-connexion-freemobile). The guy explains that setting the `mssfix 1300` instruction works on his client (he has an Android phone), but it doesn't work for me.

Do you guys have any ideas ?